# How can I decode angular.callbacks json

Tags: php, json

How can I decode this thank you in advance.

```
angular.callbacks._1({"transaction":{"token":"Lf8jxwKp3XwSTIhpmOvFbJiHL4l","created_at":"2019-11-01T11:25:02Z","updated_at":"2019-11-01T11:25:02Z","succeeded":true,"transaction_type":"AddPaymentMethod","retained":false,"message":"Succeeded!","message_key":"messages.transaction_succeeded","payment_method":{"token":"58ta8FWrvwiPlEjnwDrUvzYJSir","data":null,"metadata":null,"storage_state":"cached","email":"Iokp@iephmail.com","created_at":"2019-11-01T11:25:02Z","updated_at":"2019-11-01T11:25:02Z","errors":[],"payment_method_type":"credit_card","first_name":"Mansio","last_name":"Enioms","full_name":"Fredrick Erispe","card_type":"visa","last_four_digits":"0373","first_six_digits":"446542","month":10,"year":2025,"address1":"1961 Timbercrest Road","address2":"","city":"MARCUS","state":"IL","zip":"51035","country":"US","phone_number":"18089648560","eligible_for_card_updater":true,"shipping_address1":null,"shipping_address2":null,"shipping_city":null,"shipping_state":null,"shipping_zip":null,"shipping_country":null,"shipping_phone_number":null,"company":null,"verification_value":"XXX","number":"XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-0373","fingerprint":"a84a3e186cc102c5621c59db43dbd8522d69"}},"status":201});
```

My code

```
$json= json_decode($data, true);
echo $transaction = $json['transaction']['payment_method'];
```

It show nothing please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting any results because your json is not valid. `Json_decode` function accept only valid json.

Like this:

```
<?php

       $data = '{
    "transaction": {
        "token": "Lf8jxwKp3XwSTIhpmOvFbJiHL4l",
        "created_at": "2019-11-01T11:25:02Z",
        "updated_at": "2019-11-01T11:25:02Z",
        "succeeded": true,
        "transaction_type": "AddPaymentMethod",
        "retained": false,
        "message": "Succeeded!",
        "message_key": "messages.transaction_succeeded",
        "payment_method": {
            "token": "58ta8FWrvwiPlEjnwDrUvzYJSir",
            "data": null,
            "metadata": null,
            "storage_state": "cached",
            "email": "Iokp@iephmail.com",
            "created_at": "2019-11-01T11:25:02Z",
            "updated_at": "2019-11-01T11:25:02Z",
            "errors": [],
            "payment_method_type": "credit_card",
            "first_name": "Mansio",
            "last_name": "Enioms",
            "full_name": "Fredrick Erispe",
            "card_type": "visa",
            "last_four_digits": "0373",
            "first_six_digits": "446542",
            "month": 10,
            "year": 2025,
            "address1": "1961 Timbercrest Road",
            "address2": "",
            "city": "MARCUS",
            "state": "IL",
            "zip": "51035",
            "country": "US",
            "phone_number": "18089648560",
            "eligible_for_card_updater": true,
            "shipping_address1": null,
            "shipping_address2": null,
            "shipping_city": null,
            "shipping_state": null,
            "shipping_zip": null,
            "shipping_country": null,
            "shipping_phone_number": null,
            "company": null,
            "verification_value": "XXX",
            "number": "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-0373",
            "fingerprint": "a84a3e186cc102c5621c59db43dbd8522d69"
        }
    },
    "status": 201
}';

$json= json_decode($data, true);
print_r($json["transaction"]["payment_method"]);
```

**Output will be:**

```
Array
(
    [token] => 58ta8FWrvwiPlEjnwDrUvzYJSir
    [data] => 
    [metadata] => 
    [storage_state] => cached
    [email] => Iokp@iephmail.com
    [created_at] => 2019-11-01T11:25:02Z
    [updated_at] => 2019-11-01T11:25:02Z
    [errors] => Array
        (
        )

    [payment_method_type] => credit_card
    [first_name] => Mansio
    [last_name] => Enioms
    [full_name] => Fredrick Erispe
    [card_type] => visa
    [last_four_digits] => 0373
    [first_six_digits] => 446542
    [month] => 10
    [year] => 2025
    [address1] => 1961 Timbercrest Road
    [address2] => 
    [city] => MARCUS
    [state] => IL
    [zip] => 51035
    [country] => US
    [phone_number] => 18089648560
    [eligible_for_card_updater] => 1
    [shipping_address1] => 
    [shipping_address2] => 
    [shipping_city] => 
    [shipping_state] => 
    [shipping_zip] => 
    [shipping_country] => 
    [shipping_phone_number] => 
    [company] => 
    [verification_value] => XXX
    [number] => XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-0373
    [fingerprint] => a84a3e186cc102c5621c59db43dbd8522d69
)
```

**Note:** your valid json resides inside `angular.callbacks._1`